# Paste path from clipboard in file dialog

Tags: finder, filesystem

I have a full absolute file path on my clipboard (ie: `/Users/Noit/Pictures/Screenshot - Jul 9, 2018 3.27 PM.png`)

I then go to say Skype or gmail in my web borwser, and click "attach". This opens a file dialog box (screenshot below). In Windows, I am able to paste the file path into the dialog box and it finds it (screenshot below). Is there anyway to do this in mac?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In any "file open" dialogue, if you have a file path name in the clipboard, click ... `Command + Shift + G`.  This will open the search for folder dialogue. Paste File path name from the clipboard into the pathname field then simply paste the path name from your clipboard

[image]

Alternately, you can drag files directly from finder into your open dialogue…

[image]

As defined in the "GO" menu using Finder.app, using any of the shortcuts shown in this image, in any file open dialogue, will bring you to that folder.

[image]

Comment: I'm not on my mac to verify this at the moment, but I think it is sufficient to type "/" to bring up the path input.

Comment: @ischeriad oh wow thats cool you're right!

Comment: @wch1zpink - thanks for your edit to show you can drag file from finder to file dialog. But I think that is not related to the question/answer. Usually we can just drag and drop from the finder to the web app. So it doesnt help when absolute file path is on clipboard.

Comment: @Noitidart  You are correct. My edit does not really address your original question and is a bit off-topic, but I figured while we were on the topic of Open File dialogs, throwing in a few extra useful command tidbits wouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: Also note that if you don't have the whole path in the clipboard but you know where you're going, you can use tab-completion similar to the command line. This allows you to go to inaccessible paths like ~/Library, /etc/ or invisible folders starting with "." like ~/.ssh/ (again, from memory).

Comment: Oh wow @ischeriad that tab completion is awesome!!

Comment: It doesn't work if file is hidden such as `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: it is the year  2024 ( almost) and macOS UX still wants you to learn this trade secret.